# SQLite database recreated on application restart

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I am creating an android based Appointment management system. For storing appointments I'm using an SQLite database. The application works flawlessly but the only problem is that the Database gets recreated every time I restart the application it self. Following is my onCreate and onUpgrade methods. (PS. I used a video tutorial on creating and connecting the database. This worked fine on him. Only difference is I'm using a Mac and he was using Windows)

```
public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, DATE TEXT, TIME TEXT, TITLE TEXT, DETAIL TEXT, UNIQUE(DATE, TITLE))");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXITS" + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}
```

Just in case I have uploaded my full database connection code here, [Database.java](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Gl9uVnwKbZCDSThUQ-alFrkMdBbLylmUeaCTFvtsE4A/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Is `DATABASE_NAME` `null`?

Comment: No it is set to DATABASE_NAME = "appointment.db"

Comment: Are you using an emulator or a real device?

Comment: Using the emulator. I also tried clearing app data a couple of times. But still the same thing keeps happening

Comment: have you put a debugger-breakpoit in onCreate/onUpgrade and analysed the callstack?

Comment: I tried debugging in different ways but i cant seem to see the problem

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without seeing the entire class, but you may be inadvertently deleting the database somewhere? Look for calls to `deleteDatabase` that may be buried somewhere, particularly if you based your code of a tutorial that may have left bits and pieces of code in place.

Comment: Actually its not called anywhere, another problem is that the database update querries dont work at all

Comment: just in case my code could be found here,
[link]https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Gl9uVnwKbZCDSThUQ-alFrkMdBbLylmUeaCTFvtsE4A/edit?usp=sharing